# Why can't I access exported class's function in Webpack-ed node 8.1.0 AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, webpack-4

I'm writing an AWS Lambda function using the Node 8.1.0 runtime. My index.js looks like this:

```
import MyCustomClass from 'my-custom-class';

exports.handler = async(event) => {
  console.log('MyCustomClass.getDummy()', MyCustomClass.getDummy());
  return null;
};
```

My my-custom-class.js looks like this:

```
export default class MyCustomClass {
  constructor() {
    this.dummy = 'Hello World'
  }

  getDummy() {
    return this.dummy;
  }
}
```

I'm bundling with the following webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
  }
};
```

When I bundle my function I don't get any errors, and what I see in my resulting bundle.js looks good, but I get the following error in AWS: TypeError: my_custom_class__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.getDummy is not a function

Comment: Because you are calling it statically and the method is not static.

Comment: `static getDummy(){ /* Your code here */ }` or `new MyCustomClass().getDummy()`

Comment: So I just need `myCustomClass = new myCustomClass(); myCustomClass.getDummy();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a method in a `static` way, however, the method is not `static`.

Use the `new` keyword to create an instance of the class then you can use the method.

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  let myCustomClass = new MyCustomClass;
  console.log('MyCustomClass.getDummy()', myCustomClass.getDummy());
  return null;
};
```

Another option, is to make the method static, but then you will need to make the property that the method references static as well.

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  console.log('MyCustomClass.getDummy()', MyCustomClass.getDummy());
  return null;
}

export default class MyCustomClass {
  static getDummy() {
    return this.dummy;
  }
}
MyCustomClass.dummy = 'Hello World'
```

**Note:** I do not recommend mixing `es6` with `es5`, either stick with `export xxx` or `exports.xxx`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as soon as I'm back in the office

Comment: That did the trick. I was sure I had tried actually instantiating it with `new` previously and it didn't work, but I think at that point I was importing/exporting improperly. Either way, works now. Thanks very much!